# Removing dataframes from list of dataframes based on condition using for loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

Consider the following data named as `mat`. My objective is to count the unique values of `v1` for each `id` and store them in variable `n`. And then, I want to remove the data frame from the list if `n <= 1` and when `n >= 2`.

```
id v1 v2 
1  2  3
1  2  5
2  9  8
2  4  5
3  7  8
3  1  5
```

Here what I've tried:

```
dat  <- list()
dat2 <- list()
for (i in seq_along(unique(mat$id))){
  dat[[i]] <- data.frame(subset(mat,mat$id==unique(mat$id)[i])) 
  dat[[i]]$n <- length(unique(dat[[i]]$v1))
  if(dat[[i]]$n >= 2){
    dat2[[i]] <- dat[[i]]
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do with lists and data frames. Here's a simple way to find unique `v1` values per `id`. `tapply(mat[,"v1"],mat[,"id"],unique)`

Comment: Or counts of unique values. `tapply(mat[,"v1"],mat[,"id"],function(x) length(unique(x)))`. You may want to rephrase your question and use `dput` to share your data (I assume `mat` is a matrix, but we can't tell for sure right now).

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, my plan is to do some analysis on each data frame in the list. That's why I subset the `mat`. The `mat` is a coincidence. I meant a data frame, not a matrix. But the first data frame (`id = 1`) should be deleted since `unique(v1) = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personally, I would go for the `dplyr` approach

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 v1 = c(2,2,9,4,7,1),
                 v2 = c(3,5,8,5,8,5))
df_n <- df %>%
    group_by(id) %>% #groups the data by a variable
    summarise(n = length(unique(v1))) %>% #does a computation for each group
    filter(n >=2) #subsets based on condition
df_n
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#     id     n
#  <dbl> <int>
#1     2     2
#2     3     2
```

Now, if you want to remove any data from `df` that remains in `df_n`, you can use an `anti_join`

```
anti_join(df, df_n, by = "id") #
#  id v1 v2
#1  1  2  3
#2  1  2  5
```

If you want to keep the `id`s that remain in `df_n`, you can use the inverse, a `semi_join`

```
semi_join(df, df_n, by = "id")
#  id v1 v2
#1  2  9  8
#2  2  4  5
#3  3  7  8
#4  3  1  5
```

---

## Edit

If you want to add a new column, replace `summarize` with `mutate`. The difference between these functions is that `mutate` will return the data frame with the new evaluated expressions, and `summarize` will return a data frame with rows equal to the number of grouping combinations.

After seeing your comment, the below code should get you most of the way there, you probably don't need `semi/anti_join` for this case. Use `filter` to split the data frames how you like.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 v1 = c(2,2,9,4,7,1),
                 v2 = c(3,5,8,5,8,5)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(n = length(unique(v1))
```

Comment: Thank you very indeed. I'm looking for the last one. Is that possible to add `n` as an additional column in `semi_join(df, df_n, by = "id")`. That means for the same `id`, `n` is also the same.